# Edits to Category pages not showing

Tags: category, edit

A couple of months ago I ran a special sale on my two stores' sites. I added info to the category page's header *("Prices have been discounted an additional 25% off now through 8-31-20!
Discounted price reflected in your shopping cart")*to call attention to the additional discount. Once the sale was over I removed the verbiage, but it still shows. I can't figure out why.
https://www.optechusa.com/sidewalk-sale.html

I had made the changes in "all store views" and double checked to see that the individual store views didn't contain the extraneous info.

I'm afraid I'm a complete noob and inherited my responsibilities when our developer moved away.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try clearing the cache?

System > Tools > Cache Management > Flush Magento Cache

Comment: Thank you, Yes, I did try flushing the cache but the code, though removed from the page, still shows.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your sentence is in the database. Go in the backend and edit the category; then check the description textarea field, you are looking for the h3 tag

see screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. The odd thing is that I have edited the category, which was how I put the notification in at the beginning. But now, even after I've deleted that part of the code, and even though I've flushed the cache, it still shows. Very peculiar!

Comment: now, you may want to verify the description on the store scope is not having the data either. Also, if it has already helped you the answer as it is, it is good practice to thumb up just so that we remain appreciative of the time for each other, thanks

Comment: Thank you. (I'm very new to the forum so it's much appreciated to have tips on the etiquette of how things work!)
The contents are identical in "All Store Views" and in OP/TECH USA Store View.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out to have been an indexing issue. I got some outside help who reindexed the sites for me and now the changes are showing correctly.